# More than one Zend_Cache configuration?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

Is it possible to have two different cache instances for `Zend_Cache`? 
For instance, if I wanted to have a set of files that are stored forever unless I delete them and another set that gets invalidated every minute -- could I do that?

[Everywhere I look](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html) I always see only one frontend and backend configuration used.

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you use different `cacheTemplate` through `Zend_Cache_Manager::setCacheTemplate()` rather than using different `Zend_Cache`? Not sure I'm entirely following your logic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply create two different instances of Zend_Cache and stick them somewhere handy.  I did something like this once, instantiating the cache instances in the boostrap, and just sticking them in the registry, like this:

```
protected function _initCache(){
    $this->bootstrap('config');
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config')->myapp->cache;

    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory(
      $config->frontend->name,
      $config->backend->name,
      $config->frontend->opts->toArray(),
      $config->backend->opts->toArray()
    );
    Zend_Registry::set('cache',$cache);
    return $cache;
  }

  protected function _initUserCache(){
    $this->bootstrap('config');
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config')->myapp->othercache;

    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory(
      $config->frontend->name,
      $config->backend->name,
      $config->frontend->opts->toArray(),
      $config->backend->opts->toArray()
    );
    Zend_Registry::set('othercache',$cache);
    return $cache;

  }
```

So, there's really nothing about the design of Zend_Cache that limits the number of different caches you can have.  You can configure them all independently, using whatever front-end and back-end you like for each.

Answer (score -1):

You can use cachemanager resource for instance:

```
resources.cachemanager.foo.frontend.name = Core
resources.cachemanager.foo.frontend.options.lifetime = 300
resources.cachemanager.foo.frontend.options.automatic_serialization = true
resources.cachemanager.foo.frontend.options.cache_id_prefix = some_prefix
resources.cachemanager.foo.backend.name = Memcached
resources.cachemanager.foo.backend.options.lifetime = 300
```

"foo" is cache key, you can specify as many as you want.

Next i put cachemanager to Zend_Registry (in Bootstrap)

```
protected function _initCache()
{
        Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Caches', $this->bootstrap('cachemanager')
                                               ->getPluginResource('cachemanager')
                                               ->getCacheManager());
}
```

Usage (everywhere)

```
Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Caches')->foo
```